# Filename increment in applescript

Tags: file, applescript, increment, automator

I'm after a lightweight automator process (applescript) to detect filenames like "file_v01", "document_v03" all ending in "_vXX" to be incremented (to "file_v02" and there is suprisingly little content out there on this.

I have attempted simply detecting and removing the last two characters from the filename to no avail, and any thoughts would be great. Doesnt need to be anything fancy, just _v02 becomes _v03.

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an **AppleScript** for `Automator` which increment the last two characters from the filename

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with thisFile in input
            set {tName, nameExt} to {name, name extension} of thisFile
            if nameExt is not "" then set nameExt to "." & nameExt
            set newName to my incrementNumber(tName, nameExt)
            if newName is not "" then -- the last two characters is a number
                set name of thisFile to newName
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
    return input
end run

on incrementNumber(n, e) -- name and name extension
    set tBase to text 1 thru ((length of n) - (length of e)) of n -- get the name without extension
    try
        set thisNumber to (text -2 thru -1 of tBase) + 1 -- get the last two characters and increment
        if thisNumber < 10 then set thisNumber to "0" & thisNumber -- zero padding
        set tBase to text 1 thru -3 of tBase -- remove the last two characters
        return tBase & thisNumber & e -- the updated name (the basename without the last two characters + the number + the extension)
    end try
    return "" --  the last two characters is not a number
end incrementNumber
```

Comment: This is awesome! However can I remove the dialog to 'find a file' and it just increments whatever file automator has as incoming connection?

Comment: I updated the script to run in an Automator workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script that you want.

You need to set first the type of separator between your file name and the counter. You then need to define how many digit your counter should have.

I assume you may have some text after the counter in your file name (like the file extension !) :

```
set Separator to "_v" -- separator between name and counter
set DigitsCount to 2 -- assuming only 2 digits for counter like 01, 02, ...99

set myName to "testxxx_v07_Copy.txt" -- example for the test

set PosSep to offset of Separator in myName
    if PosSep is 0 then
-- no separator, then no counter..do what's required !
else
set BaseName to text 1 thru (PosSep - 1) of myName
set myCount to (text from (PosSep + (length of Separator)) to (PosSep + (length of Separator) + DigitsCount - 1) of myName) as integer
set PostName to text from (PosSep + (length of Separator) + DigitsCount) to -1 of myName
end if
-- convert the counter to +1 in string with '0' before
set newCount to "00000" & (myCount + 1) as string
set newCount to text from ((length of newCount) - DigitsCount + 1) to -1 of newCount
set NextName to BaseName & Separator & newCount & PostName

-- BaseName now contains the basic name before the counter
-- newCount contains the new counter value (+1) as string formatted with x digits
-- PostName contains the current value of myName after the counter
-- NextName contains your new file name with new counter and extension if any
```